# Mapping HTML table into JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm total newbie in front-end and I got pretty simple task to do with JavaScript. Long story short, I got a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:80%; text-align: center;">Account number</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="account in model.accounts track by $index">
    <td>{{ account}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="removeAccount($index)" class="btn" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I need to map those values into JSON that will look like this:

```
"Accounts": {
  "number": "model.accounts",
  "otherinfo": "default_value"
}
```

While at this point I got only number, `otherinfo` will be added later.

I'v tried something like this:

```
this.$scope.model= {
  accounts: []
}
```

I've checked, it holds all my account numbers I've put into the table.

Now I need to make array of few account objects out of this, that I'll later use inside `JSON.stringify()` I'v tried this:

```
var accounts = [{
  number: "",
  otherinfo: "",
}]

var x;
for (x = 0; x < $scope.model.accounts.length; x++) {
  accounts[x].number = $scope.model.accounts.nrbList[x];
}
```

And for instance, If I add 2 elements to my table, I would expect my array to contain 2 objects, both having values from table and default value at `otherinfo` which is an empty string.

Unfortunately, I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'number' of undefined
```

Comment: Put `accounts[x] = {};` before `accounts[x].number = $scope.model.accounts.nrbList[x];` in the for loop.

Comment: Push a new object into the array every iteration of the loop